# matplotlib: color by dict without normalization

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

My goal is is to use a colormap that maps via a dict, a given number to a given color.

However, **matplotlib** seems to have **normalized** the number.

For example, I first created a custom colormap use `seaborn`, and feed it into `plt.scatter`

```
import seaborn as sns

colors = ['pumpkin', "bright sky blue", 'light green', 'salmon', 'grey', 'pale grey']
pal = sns.xkcd_palette(colors)
sns.palplot(pal)
```

[image: palette]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap = ListedColormap(pal.as_hex())
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [0, 1, 2]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=[0, 1, 2], s=500, cmap=cmap)  # I'd like to get color ['pumpkin', "bright sky blue", 'light green']
```

but, it gives me color `['pumpkin', 'salmon', 'pale grey']`

[image: scatter]

In short:
**colormap**:

[image: palette]

getting color 0, 1, and 2 (**desired**):

[image]

but `matplotlib` gives:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A colormap is always normalized between 0 and 1. A scatter plot will by default normalize the values given to the `c` argument, such that the colormap ranges from the minimum to the maximum value. However, you may of course define your own normalization. In this case it would be `vmin=0, vmax=len(colors)`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

colors = ['xkcd:pumpkin', "xkcd:bright sky blue", 'xkcd:light green', 
          'salmon', 'grey', 'xkcd:pale grey']
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)

x = range(3)
y = range(3)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=range(3), s=500, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=len(colors))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For me, I was using `c = df['my_color_column']`, and using `vmax = max(c)` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the colors as a sequence of numbers (`[0,1,2]` in your case), then those numbers will be mapped to colors using the normalization. You can instead directly specify a sequence of colors:

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [0, 1, 2]
clrs = [0, 1, 2]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=[pal[c] for c in clrs], s=500)
```

gives

[image]