# Simple scalar to RGB color mapping with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Say I have a 10x10 1-dimensional ndarray in which all possible values are [0, 100, 200]. I want to manually create a very simple colormap `manual_cmap` that tells matplotlib:

```
if value==0   : make this pixel black
if value==100 : make this pixel yellow
if value==200 : make this pixel red
etc.
```

Then, I could use this `manual_cmap` to save my images with the desired colors without having to use more memory by converting them to 3-dimensional RGB arrays:

```
plt.imsave('colored_image.png', oneD_array, cmap=manual_cmap)
```

**P.s** I have seen some examples out there for creating custom colormaps but I haven't found any simple example that would allow me to manually define a simple lookup-table like colormap for just a few value-color pairs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: color by dict without normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367771/matplotlib-color-by-dict-without-normalization)

Comment: Take a look at `ListedColormap` in `matplotlib.colors`